# ShowAchievementsUI(); don't want to appear on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am using the official [PlayGameServices plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) for Unity, and have been following the installation to the point. Authentication seems to work like a charm, but when I want to do the `ShowAchievementsUI();`, nothing happends. No UI, no errors, no crashes.

Ive been googling around for a while, it seems other people have hit this problem, but with no solution in sight.

My code at the moment is :

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

void Start() {
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    LoginSocialGamecenter();
}


public static void LoginSocialGamecenter() {
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
        Social.ShowAchievementsUI (); Debug.Log("Pancakes!");
        return;
    }
}
```

And "Pancakes!" comes out perfectly. Authentication UI on first install also shows up nicely. It fails on all devices I have, but the debug message shows up perfectly on Android.

According to the documentation, it should work as described:

Showing the Achievements UI

> To show the built-in UI for all leaderboards, call
>   Social.ShowAchievementsUI.
>
> ```
> using GooglePlayGames;
> using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
> ...
> // show achievements UI
> Social.ShowAchievementsUI(); 
>
> This will show a standard UI appropriate for the look and feel of the platform (Android or iOS).
> ```

Comment: I have no experience with the Unity plugin, but when I had trouble with Google Play Games stuff not displaying it was due to using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for the Activity in the manifest. Might not be your problem, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: Don't seem to have that anywhere in my manifest, but thanks for the input.

Comment: In your description you say "It fails on all devices, I have, but shows up perfectly on Android." - What type of devices does it fail on?

Comment: Bad formulation from my part. I ment the debug message.

Comment: By any chance if you have not gone through checklist.. First point says ...Implement at least five achievements in your game.

To qualify for Play Games services branding, your game must provide players with at least five achievements that are distinct and unlockable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but possibly the method is not being called from the main thread? Or the Activity isn't in the right state in its lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Akhil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677824/akhil) got it right. There needs to be more than five achievements or the window won't appear.

It will make no error reports on this, simply return false.